# How to add extra context with Haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have set up Haystack search to my website. Searching works fine and I really like it. I have a problem with adding extra context. I want to "push" objects from 3 models, to my template. 
First object is my search result, two another should be additional. My question is: how can I pass objects from another models. Here is my **search_indexes.py** file:

```
import datetime
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from filmy.models import Video, Page, Category

class VideoIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = CharField(model_attr='title')
    description = CharField(model_attr='description')
    date = DateTimeField(model_attr='date')

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        # """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return Video.objects.filter(date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())

    def extra_context(self):
        return {
            'categories': Category.objects.all().order_by('-name'),
            'list_of_pages': Page.objects.all().order_by('id'),
        }

site.register(Video, VideoIndex)
```

Searching works fine, but I want to have a list of all Categories and list of all Pages also (I use them in base.html template. My solution doesn't work. I tried second one with subclass:

```
import datetime
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from filmy.models import Video, Page, Category

class VideoIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = CharField(model_attr='title')
    description = CharField(model_attr='description')
    date = DateTimeField(model_attr='date')

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        # """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return Video.objects.filter(date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())

site.register(Video, VideoIndex)

class VideoSearchIndex(VideoIndex):
    def extra_context(self):
        extra = super(VideoSearchIndex, self).extra_context()
        extra['categories'] = Category.objects.all().order_by('-name')
        extra['list_of_pages'] = Page.objects.all().order_by('id')
        return extra
```

But this code also doesn't work. I have no idea how to easly implement additional models to my search results.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my problem. I couldn't solve it with **extra_context** function, so I used  **TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS** to set global variables in my template.

It's quite convenient solution because I don't need to use extra_context functions in my view to all my models. I just set global variables in one file in one definition. It increased readability of views.py file.